# Movie/show about interracial relationship and drugs

Tags: identify-this-movie, identify-this-tv-show

I am looking for a TV show or a movie. The couple I remember from the show/movie were not the main characters.

The show/movie reminded me of Breaking Bad and The Fast and the Furious.

Plot details of any scenes I remember: a girl sees a boy/man run away from the police and then he throws a small bag of drugs in a bush near her house. The girl throws the bag in her bedroom window to prevent the police from finding the bag. I remember the police being abusive/violent towards her.

The boy/man and the girl became a couple after a while and she returned the bag to him. She was black, he was white or Mexican. As far as I remember he was almost mute/never said anything. Her father didn't like them being together. Both her father and the man were involved in drug trading and I think her father was feared by the whole neighbourhood because of this.

I also believe that the girl got involved with drug trade after a while and went from being an innocent girl to be feared like her father.

It's set the USA/Mexico region, a warm place, city. (Mexico, California, maybe even Cuba.) I probably bought it on DVD or Netflix/HBO/etc. around 2015-2017. It's fairly new (max. 10 years old?). I'm almost certain that it's from the USA. It wasn't animated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for the season 4 *Orange Is the New Black* episode [Power Suit](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4800062/combined) released in 2016. Though I only watch the show on and off, I fortunately saw this one. The episode focuses on [Maria](http://orange-is-the-new-black.wikia.com/wiki/Maria_Ruiz), **a dark-skinned Dominican woman whose father is the head of a drug cartel**, and flashes back to her earlier days [where she comes across a young Mexican drug dealer](http://www.afterellen.com/tv/492905-orange-new-black-recap-4-2-suit-fits/2):

> Maria goes to her room, where she sees a young Yadriel running from the cops. He tosses a bag of drugs into the bushes, and she sneaks out to reclaim it before the cops can grab it. She tosses the drugs into her window without the cops seeing her, but she is still stopped and frisked because racism.

Maria and Yadriel later form a relationship, **which her father disapproves of because Yadriel is Mexican and not Dominican.** You can see part of the scene where she finds the bag of drugs in this reaction video around 3:35: